# XPath/JSONPath search of arrays

Tags: json, xpath, jmeter, jsonpath

Our REST API is returning an array of nested objects. Using XPath or JSONPath, I would like to extract the id elements of each top level array object but not the children's id elements.

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "child":{
         "id":"a"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "child":{
         "id":"b"
      }
   }
]
```

The expected output is 1, 2 and NOT 1, a, 2, b.

Can anybody help with the query syntax? I have the example at http://jsfiddle.net/dqvrfvc1/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you have `jmeter` in your tags here is a solution for it:

JSON Path Expression should look like: `$[*].id`

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSON Path Extractor Demo]

References:

- [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)
- [JSON Path: Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the `id` at a specific level:

```
search = JSON.search(data, '/*/*/id')
```

See the update here: http://jsfiddle.net/dqvrfvc1/5/

If we dump the XML to the console (`console.log(JSON.toXML(data));`) we see:

```
<d:data xmlns:d="defiant-namespace" d:constr="Array" d:mi="9">
    <d:item d:mi="4">
        <id d:constr="String" d:mi="1">1</id>
        <child d:mi="3">
            <id d:constr="String" d:mi="2">a</id>
        </child>
    </d:item>
    <d:item d:mi="8">
        <id d:constr="String" d:mi="5">2</id>
        <child d:mi="7">
            <id d:constr="String" d:mi="6">b</id>
        </child>
    </d:item>
</d:data>
```

This means that instead of `/*/*/id`, we can be even more specific with:

```
search = JSON.search(data, '/d:data/d:item/id')
```

Note: Namespace selection isn't possible, so there doesn't seem to be the need to bind the `d:` namespace prefix to the `defiant-namespace` uri.

Also, take a look at the "XPATH EVALUATOR" section of http://defiantjs.com and switch between XML and JSON views to see how the JSON is represented in XML. This will help you understand the the data structure and at what level `id` would be found.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned XPath: in XPath 3.1 this is

```
parse-json($data)?*?id
```